# Adding a Column of Data Table if Rows Match

Tags: excel, vba

I have a data table of 5 different columns. I would like to get the average of one of the columns if the 4 previous columns match one another for that row. For example, if rows 1-3 match, I would like to get the average of column 5 for rows 1-3. The specific values in the columns will be changing so I can't use a VLOOKUP / INDEX and MATCH because I do not necessarily know what I am looking for. I would ideally like an output table that lists the averages and the values that these averages correspond too. Below is an oversimplified example -

Raw Data

New Jersey  Dec  Red    Soccer   2
New York    Dec  Blue   Hockey   5
New York    Dec  Blue   Hockey   1
Maine       Mar  Blue   Soccer   6
Maryland    Feb  Red    Soccer   9

Would result in

New Jersey  Dec  Red    Soccer   2
New York    Dec  Blue   Hockey   3
Maine       Mar  Blue   Soccer   6
Maryland    Feb  Red    Soccer   9

Comment: Easiest way to do this would be by making a pivot table using your data.

Comment: Are the duplicate rows always consecutive? Or can they be mixed between other rows?

Answer (score 0):

Place the following routine in a standard code module. Then run it with the data sheet active.

```
Sub Condense()
    Dim c&, i&, j&, k&, m&, cols&, v, w, bMatch As Boolean, r As Range
    Set r = [a2:e6]
    v = r.Resize(r.Rows.Count + 1)
    cols = UBound(v, 2)
    ReDim w(1 To UBound(v), 1 To cols)
    For i = 2 To UBound(v)
        k = i - 1
        bMatch = True
        For j = 1 To cols - 1
            If v(i, j) <> v(k, j) Then
                bMatch = False: Exit For
            End If
        Next
        If bMatch Then
            m = k
        Else
            c = c + 1
            For j = 1 To cols
                w(c, j) = v(k, j)
            Next
            If m Then
                w(c, cols) = Application.Average(Range(r(m, cols), r(k, cols)))
            End If
            m = 0
        End If
    Next
    r.Resize(UBound(w), cols).Offset(, cols + 1) = w
End Sub
```

Note: you can edit the location of the data by adjusting the range on line #2.

Note: a condensed copy of the data with the averaging done will be written to the right of the data range.

Comment: @S.Mac Please let me know if this worked out for you. If you need help, I'm here.